# TS2345: Argument of type '(req: any, res: any, ctx: any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HttpResponseResolver<PathParams<string>,

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library, msw

Getting error in React TypeScript test case with mock data. **I got the following error:**

> TS2345: Argument of type '(req: any, res: any, ctx: any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HttpResponseResolver<PathParams, DefaultBodyType, undefined>'.

Test case code is

```
import { http } from 'msw'; 
export const handlers = [
http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(
        ctx.status(200),
        ctx.json([
            {
                name: 'Leanne Graham'
            },
            {
                name: 'Ervin Howell'
            },
            {
                name: 'Clementine Bauch'
            },
        ])
    )
  })
];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using MSW v2+, please see the v2 documentation [Respond with a mocked response](https://mswjs.io/docs/concepts/response-resolver#respond-with-a-mocked-response), the correct way is:

```
import { http, HttpResponse } from 'msw';

export const handlers = [
  http.get(
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
    ({ request, params, requestId }) => {
      return HttpResponse.json(
        [
          {
            name: 'Leanne Graham',
          },
          {
            name: 'Ervin Howell',
          },
          {
            name: 'Clementine Bauch',
          },
        ],
        { status: 200 }
      );
    }
  ),
];
```

package version:

```json
"msw": "^2.2.1",
```